# Adding a List to SQL database (Entity Database)

Tags: c#, sql

I got a database with members, each member has a list of sports they do.
now I want to loop through a listbox and add every selected item to my database.

This is my database :

[image]

And this is my code :

```
foreach (var item in sportCheckedListBox.CheckedIndices)
            {
                int sportindex = Convert.ToInt32(item.ToString()) + 1;
                var queryResult = from sp in context.Sports
                                  where sp.sportnr == sportindex
                                  select sp;
                foreach (var sport in queryResult)
                {
                    myMember.Sports.Add(sport);
                }
            }
```

This looks kinda 'shady', how could I do this better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I'd do for sure is move the query out of the loop. Queries should never exist in loops for performance and maintainability reasons. LINQ knows how to translate a `(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, ... }).Contains(column)` construct into a `WHERE column IN (0, 1, 2, ...)` statement, so let's use that:

```
// Get all checked items together
var lookupIndices = sportCheckedListBox.CheckedIndices.Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(item.ToString()) + 1);

// Find all matching sport numbers
var queryResult = from sp in context.Sports
                  where lookupIndices.Contains(sp.sportnr)
                  select sp;

// Now loop over the results
foreach (var sport in queryResult)
{
    myMember.Sports.Add(sport);
}

// save changes
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do `AddRange`:

```
myMember.Sports.AddRange(queryResult);
myMember.Sports.SaveChanges()
```

You may need to covert `queryResult` to an `IEnumerable` type if it's not already though.

Comment: queryResult is not a list, so does not have AddRange().

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with your approach, but you can achieve it more concisely with Linq.

Instead of your `foreach` loop, if you always want to assign a new list you could use

```
myMember.Sports = queryResult.ToList();
```

If you want to instead concatenate results to an existing list, you could use

```
myMember.Sports = myMember.Sports.Concat(queryResult.ToList());
```

If you wanted to do the same as above, but not have any duplicates (as defined by the object you are adding), instead

```
myMember.Sports = myMember.Sports.Union(queryResult.ToList());
```